# How to check is RabbitMQ get task from celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I use django-celery for tasks that run longer time then usual. All time until task is running client check the Result of the current task. Problem is that if celeryd does not run or it is terminated because of some error, check for the task still give result PENDING.  If there is problem with the Worker I would like to give that information to the client and it should stop to check the status of the task and the task should be terminate.
Code what I use for check status of the task is:

```
res = AsyncResult(task_id)
result = res.status
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into celery [Monitoring](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html), specifically look into [Flower: Real-time Celery web-monitor](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for one of these functions:

`djcelery.celery.control.inspect().ping()`
`djcelery.celery.control.inspect().active_queues()`

checkout my example django-celery example project:
https://github.com/brentpayne/django-celery-example/blob/master/polls/management/commands/worker_count.py

and this celery document:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers